# In Windows, does "The exception unknown software exception (0x40000015) occurred in the application" mean STATUS_FATAL_APP_EXIT?

Tags: windows, exception

At shutdown (initiated by an UPS) my application crashes and a messagebox appears.

The text in the messagebox is "The exception unknown software exception (0x40000015) occurred in the application".

I browsed `ntstatus.h` and found `STATUS_FATAL_APP_EXIT`? If it were right, why the message box say "unknown software exception"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, 0x40000015 means STATUS_FATAL_APP_EXIT.  Your app causes an unhandled runtime exception during shutdown.  Some  runtime exceptions are actually handled if you don't handle them yourself, and some of these default handlers call `abort()`.  By default, `abort` calls:

```
_call_reportfault(_CRT_DEBUGGER_ABORT, STATUS_FATAL_APP_EXIT, EXCEPTION_NONCONTINUABLE);
```

`abort` is a generic termination - it doesn't know what specific exception prompted it to be called, hence the generic 'unknown software exception' message.

One path to abort is via the _purecall exception - calling an unimplemented pure virtual call.

Gleaned from purevirt.c and abort.c in the Visual Studio\VC\crt\src directory.

MSDN has [documentation on overriding the default pure call exception handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t296ys27.aspx).

Here are some related  questions:

- [Capturing R6025 pure virtual call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224163/capturing-r6025-pure-virtual-call)
- [Where do "pure virtual function call" crashes come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99552/where-do-pure-virtual-function-call-crashes-come-from)
- [Shutdown exception handling for Win32/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798262/shutdown-exception-handling-for-win32-c)

Comment: sean e wrote: "Some runtime exceptions are actually handled if you don't handle them yourself". May you please give me a reference to the subject? MSDN? Thank you.