# Application Pool crashing?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, iis-7, biztalk

I have a Web Service running on IIS7.5. BizTalk sends the data to WS. WS open SharePoint object model and will does some transactions. After couple of BizTalk calls WS application is crashing with below information in the EventViewer.

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7afa2
Faulting module name: MSVCR80.dll, version: 8.0.50727.6195, time stamp: 0x4dcdd833
Exception code: 0x40000015
Fault offset: 0x0000000000006a68
Faulting process id: 0x2010
Faulting application start time: 0x01cd0161a09e2134
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.6195_none_88e41e092fab0294\MSVCR80.dll
```

System Logs:

> A process serving application pool 'WebServices' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process id was '8208'. The data field contains the error number.

Comment: Not an exact dupe, but this info might help track down the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115611/in-windows-does-the-exception-unknown-software-exception-0x40000015-occurred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last time I crashed IIS was because I accidentally modeled a constructor so that it'd enter to an infinite loop. If you're all managed code it is really hard for you to crash IIS unless you're hitting/filling the memory infinitely.

I'd recommend you to run a profiler on your code, and get help from Visual Studio's Code Analyze tools. See if you're disposing connections, or you have any infinite loops like I did. It's usually us, not the framework or the hardware :)

ps: if you have disposable objects, make sure you're using the "using" blocks, best way to make sure you're disposing stuff. (Code Analysis will point them out eventually)

ps2: another good way of understanding what's wrong may be logging the critical events -or stuff that you are suspicious about- on a text file. As you may know many logging libraries are available for dotnet (i'd go for [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/))

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the SharePoint object model I think there is a good possibility of what detay is saying but I am not sure this would lead to an application fault. I think you would probably see out of memory exceptions. It is surprising that this is not a BizTalk application fault.

If you do not see anything after doing profiling and reviewing your code, I would contact Microsoft Support about this issue. It can be difficult to diagnose an application fault and a call to support will get to the bottom of the problem much faster.

Thanks,